# Restore override cursor not for entire application

Tags: c++, qt, qcursor

I have a large application with many widgets and windows.

At some moment I restore the cursor for entire application. 
I need to keep it "customised" (as it was) for one frame. 
I set it for the frame to be "customised" again, but it still **restores for 1 millisecond** and it is **noticeable**.

So the states of my cursor are: "Customised" - "Normal" - "Customised".
How can I skip changing cursor for one(current) frame? But restore it for all other windows (so it is normal again)?

Answer (score 0):

Restore override cursor for all application, but set cursor to your frame.

Use `setCursor()` method.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#cursor-prop

As documentation said about `setOverrideCursor()`:

This cursor will be displayed in all the application's widgets until `restoreOverrideCursor()` or another `setOverrideCursor()` is called.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setOverrideCursor

So you can't restore cursor for all widgets instead of one, you should use `setCursor()` method.